# Find time difference in both hours and minutes in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to find the time difference between datetimes in both hours and mins in R? For example in

```
difftime("2020-09-14 18:01:31   ", "2020-09-14 17:47:38", units = "hours")
```

should give `00:14` in a format like `(hh:mm)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this in base R :

```
get_in_hm <- function(time1, time2) {
  format(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(difftime(time1, time2, units = 'secs')), 
         origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%H:%M')  
}

get_in_hm("2020-09-14 18:01:31", "2020-09-14 17:47:38")
#[1] "00:13"
```

Get the `difftime` output in seconds, convert to numeric, consider this as seconds since epoch and return the hour and minute from the captured datetime.

---

If you want to round the difference you can use :

```
get_in_hm <- function(time1, time2) {
  format(as.POSIXct(round(as.numeric(difftime(time1,time2,units = 'mins'))) * 60,
          origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%H:%M')  
}

get_in_hm("2020-09-14 18:01:31", "2020-09-14 17:47:38")
#[1] "00:14"
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution will not exactly give you what you need, but is simple enough.

```
library(lubridate)
d <- difftime("2020-09-14 18:01:31   ", "2020-09-14 17:47:38", units = "mins") %>% 
  as_hms()

d
# 00:13:53
```